# MVC folder chooser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using c# ASP.NET MVC with the razor engine.

I have done a file chooser but what I need to do next is a **folder chooser**.
Once the user chooses the folder, I need to go and get all the files in that folder and do some processing Please let me know if you have done a folder chooser.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: You're looking at flash, silverlight or ActiveX object. Nothing from a form control is going to give you that ability (for security reasons).

Comment: If he already has a 'file chooser' maybe it is about uploading multiple files from a folder from the client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it in ASP.Net/MVC, or any other technology using just HTML/JavaScript in browser: HTML does not provide ability to browse folder on client nor upload all files from given folder.

You need some sort of full trusted client side code to do so.

Comment: Thanks. What do you think a suitable solution if it is not possible. I was thinking of the user choosing a file and from there, I can figure out the folder and iterate through all of the files in that folder. Please let me know if you agree or disagree with this being a viable solution

Comment: @NatePet, it is perfectly fine solution as long as you implement it from full trust code (the one that user must install). You just can't do it using sandboxed JavaScript code that browser provides.